# How to make a quick/fast build of a single recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am developing a driver on Yocto target.

For this explanation, I will use the terminology:

- embedded-machine: the target of the Yocto project.
- host-machine: the desktop machine on which I work, where the Yocto project is cloned, and where bitbake is executed.

Every time I make some change, I can obviously try to build on my host-machine, but as the hardware is very different, there is no way to test it there.

So the procedure is:

```
devtool build MyDriver
devtool deploy-target -Ss MyDriver root@<ip> # ip of the embedded-machine
ssh root@<ip>
insmod /lib/modules/<kernel_version>/MyDriver.ko
sleep 10
rmmod MyDriver
dmesg -t | tail
```

Note: The project is, for now, just added into the `<build>/sources/...` and added with `devtool add...`

This works, however the first step `devtool build MyDriver` seems to want to build all the linux kernel each time, which make the build of a simple <1000lines driver taking several minutes.

I want to speed-up this procedure, by building only `MyDriver`, not all the dependent recipes. (Because building 10 times a day a 5min-compilation, is already 50min, or about 10% of my day just waiting).

**Is there a way to call directly oe_runmake ? or bitbake only for that specific recipe?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following steps:
**devtool modify linux**
This will fetch, extract and patch (if necessary) the package you specified to so called "workspace" (build/workspace/sources/).
After that you can build, test and play with your kernel with standard toolchain (make, gcc, cross compile) in that directory. This will be as fast as possible, like you work with kernel usually, because you skip steps that Yocto does: fetching, unpacking, patching and building inside it. Also you skip the process of starting of Yocto itself (which takes time too).